# Show posts in "image" format when viewed in category page, but with comments in blog

Tags: categories, comments, gallery

I am working on an artist's website.  She wants each image to show up in the blog, and to category pages like "paintings", "calligraphy", etc.  When viewing the category pages, the images should be displayed without comments.  But when the images are viewed in the blog, they should have a comment section.  Ideally the category page posts could link back to the blog view, but this is optional.  As far as I can tell, you can only choose the format of a post on a per-post basis.  Is there any way to make a category page apply a format to all of its posts?

Comment: Have you had a chance to look at the answer from @toscho - I believe it will enlighten you on this.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `category.php` with a customized loop that doesn’t mention the comments. See [Template Hierarchy: Category display](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Category_display) for details and [search or site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22category.php%22) for some examples.